# GLSL 1.20: sending attribute causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I need to pass an attribute variable to the shader, to know how to compute `gl_Position`. This value should be different for any object drawn. This is the declaration:

```
attribute int drawText;
```

According to it's value I decide how to compute `gl_Position`. This is hot I pass it in the c++ program:

```
// Pass some uniforms
GLint location= glGetAttribLocation(program_id, (char*)"drawText");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
glVertexAttribI1i(location,1);
glutSolidCube(15);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(location);
```

But I get segmentation fault. I tried to comment the line where I send the attribute (`glVertexAttribI1i`), and the program doesn't crash in this case. What could the problem be?

Comment: I believe you want to use uniforms, not attributes. `glVertexAttrib` is  meant to be used in instant mode,like glColor, glNormal etc.

Comment: Also integer attributes are not supported in GLSL 1.20, you need at least (IIRC) 1.30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer vertex attributes requires OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL >= 1.30.

Maybe you are using GLEW? You should check that `(void*)(glVertexAttribI1i) != 0` before using it.

Moreover, when an attribute has the same value for each vertex, like in the snippet you posted, you should use uniforms.

Comment: The code snipped I posted is just a part of the program, for each object drawn I want to pass a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type is the same, or the attribute name "drawText" is correct.